# compare input to multidimensional array elements

Tags: python, if-statement, multidimensional-array

def Intro():
    print("******************************************************\nWhat do you want to do?\n\n\tZ\t=\tGet Total Sales by Zip code\n\tC\t=\tGet Total Sales by Coffee Type\n\tG\t=\tGet Grand Total Sales of all Coffee Sales\n\tHZ\t=\tGet Highest Sales by Zip Code\n\tHC\t=\tGet Highest Sales by Coffee Type\n\tE\t=\tExit\n******************************************************")

## Zip code totals

def Code_Totals(Items,Code_Amounts):
     Zipcode=input("Enter the zip code:\t")

```
 if (Zipcode == Code_Amounts[0][0]):
     print("Ham")
```

def Main():
                              #Item name                                                           Itemprince
    Items=[["Cafe Mocha","Cafe Latte","Cafe Regular","Cafe Regular Decaf","Cafe Caramel"],[3.50,4.00,2.50,2.50,4.50]]
       #Array type      Zip codes                  Mocha/Latte/Regular/Decaf/Caramel       0/1/2/3/4/5
    Code_Amounts=[[48093,48088,48026,48066],[180,270,240,200],[100,330,310,230],[200,160,450,350,],[180,150,100,110],[150,250,320,360]]
    Intro()
    Choice=input("Enter your Choice ==>\t")

```
while Choice != "E":
    if Choice == "Z":
        Code_Totals(Items,Code_Amounts)
```

Main()

Comment: are you entering 48093?

Comment: You're passing `Zipcode` to the function and it's actual name is `zipcode`. Case matters!

Comment: Please post your actual code. `Def` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Code_Totals(Code_Amounts,Zipcode):
    if Zipcode == Code_Amounts[0][0]:
        print("Hello")
def Main():
    Code_Amounts=[[48093,48088,48026,48066],[180,270,240,200],[100,330,310,230],    [200,160,450,350,],[180,150,100,110],[150,250,320,360]]
zipcode=input("Enter the zip code:\t")
Code_Totals(Code_Amounts,zipcode)

Main()
```

`Def` is not valid and `Zipcode` should be `zipcode`